# PHP crawler exception

Tags: php, web-crawler

Below is my code which outputs the content which is present under Plot tab on a wiki page, I am using getElementById and it is throwing some exception which I pasted below, can someone modify it to work.
Thanks in Advance.

```
<?php
/**
 * Downloads a web page from $url, selects the the element by $id
 * and returns it's xml string representation.
 */
//Taking input
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) /* i.e. the PHP code is executed only when someone presses Submit button in the below given HTML Form */
{
$var = $_POST['var'];   // Here $var is the input taken from user.
} 
function getElementByIdAsString($url, $id, $pretty = true) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

    if(!$doc) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load $url");
    }

    // Obtain the element
    $element = $doc->getElementById($id);

    if(!$element) {
        throw new Exception("An element with id $id was not found");
    }

    if($pretty) {
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
    }

    // Return the string representation of the element
    return $doc->saveXML($element);
}

// call it:
echo getElementByIdAsString('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Too_Had_a_Love_Story', 'Plot');
?>
```

Exception is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'An element with id Plot was not found' in C:\xampp\htdocs\example2.php:23 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\example2.php(35): getElementByIdAsString() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\example2.php on line 23
```

Comment: And what's not to understand? There is no element with the id `Plot` in the DOM document.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois The page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Too_Had_a_Love_Story has id=Plot in source code which needs to be returned, and it is working for some other urls.

Answer (score 0):

I try your code and it works and return `<span class="mw-headline" id="Plot">Plot</span>`. I think your problem in using [`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) with `@`:

```
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
```

Because this method returns

> bool true on success or false on failure

And sometimes it return false (for example 403 from wikipedia for many requests) and your dom element is empty. In this case your `$element = $doc->getElementById($id);` can't find this element.

Try to change your code to:

```
<?php
/**
 * Downloads a web page from $url, selects the the element by $id
 * and returns it's xml string representation.
 */
//Taking input
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) /* i.e. the PHP code is executed only when someone presses Submit button in the below given HTML Form */
{
    $var = $_POST['var'];   // Here $var is the input taken from user.
}
function getElementByIdAsString($url, $id, $pretty = true) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $loadResult = @$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

    if(!$doc || !$loadResult) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load $url");
    }

    // Obtain the element
    $element = $doc->getElementById($id);

    if(!$element) {
        throw new Exception("An element with id $id was not found");
    }

    if($pretty) {
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
    }

    // Return the string representation of the element
    return $doc->saveXML($element);
}

// call it:
echo getElementByIdAsString('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Too_Had_a_Love_Story', 'Plot');
?>
```

Wkipedia can be unavailable for your script (some sites block parser scripts). Try to use curl to get status_code for your response

```
$url = 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Too_Had_a_Love_Story';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$html = curl_exec($ch); 
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed to load https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Too_Had_a_Love_Story' in C:\xampp\htdocs\example2.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\example2.php(35): getElementByIdAsString() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\example2.php on line 16

Comment: Yes, wikipedia can be unavailable for your script (some sites block parser scripts). Try to use curl to get status_code for your response

$url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Too_Had_a_Love_Story';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

Comment: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed